# JavaFX MenuBar strange behaviour with CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am buliding a simple GUI with menubar for my application and I encounter a strange problem.

adminChooseAction.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.sadzbr.controller.AdminChooseActionController"
>
    <MenuBar>
        <Menu text="Option">
            <MenuItem text="A"/>
            <MenuItem text="B"/>
            <MenuItem text="C"/>
            <MenuItem text="D"/>
        </Menu>
    </MenuBar>

    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../../css/Main.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
</VBox>
```

main.css

```
.error-bar {
    -fx-fill: #B00020;
}

.btn {
    -fx-background-color: #6200EE;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.btn-large {
    -fx-font-size: 32;
    -fx-pref-width: 300;
}

.display-center {
    -fx-alignment: center;
}

.display-right {
    -fx-alignment: right;
}

.container {
    -fx-padding: 80;
    -fx-spacing: 10;
    -fx-font-size: 16;
    -fx-pref-height: 100%;
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.text-center {
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}

.h1 {
    -fx-font-size: 24;
}

.button-grid {
    -fx-pref-width: 100%;
    -fx-hgap: 20;
}

.button-grid-button {
    -fx-pref-width: 300;
}

.choice-box {
    -fx-pref-width: 900;
}

.form-control {
    -fx-min-width: 300;
}
```

The controller for this fxml file have only handlers for buttons and don't affect on scene style.
With this file my program looks like this:
[Screenshot of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFRxu.png)

I add the green color to .container to show that this class cause a problem. I don't know why the MenuBar is stylized by this class. When I delete a stylesheet from this fxml the problem disappears. The VBox and MenuBar don't have any style classes. 
Thank you in advice for your answers that will indicate the source of the problem.

Comment: `MenuBar` has an internal component with style class `container` (you can see this, e.g., in the [source code for modena.css](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L1500)). It really should be documented in the CSS documentation, but isn't. Either use a different style class name, or be more specific in your selector for those styles. (I agree that neither of these are particularly robust, but CSS just lacks the same level of encapsulation that Java has.)

Comment: @James_D It fix the problem. Thank you for your answer.